# Tool for migrating data from Cassandra to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, cassandra

We're using Cassandra for data store, but want to migrate data out of Cassandra and into MySQL on a daily basis so that marketing/product users can query data independently using an SQL syntax.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 5):

You can access your cassandra data via SQL using Hive, which is integrated into the DataStax Brisk distribution.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/brisk/about_hive

Comment: Thanks tjake. Totally aware of Hive, but I still would like to know if there is an easy export tool to MySQL DBs. Are you aware of one?